# How do I open a child Form centered over its Parent?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am making my program multi-threaded because it is a server manager for Bukkit (Minecraft) which is pretty heavy for some systems. Now I am facing a little problem. When I want to open a new child form I can't tell it to centerparent. It just doesn't do what I tell the form to do. I have found a workaround for this but I don't know if it can be done more easy or if I have to change something else.

This is the code I have atm:
**Works**

```
private void ThreadFrmSettings()
{
    Form frmSettings = new frmSettings();
    frmSettings.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    frmSettings.Location = new Point(Location.X + (Width - frmSettings.Width) / 2, Location.Y + (Height - frmSettings.Height) / 2);
    frmSettings.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Doesnt work**

```
var frmSettings = new frmSettings();
frmSettings.ShowDialog();
```

Is this behavior normal? Thanks!

Comment: What about `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;`  property of the `From`?

Comment: What about the multi-threading is bothering you particularly? The default behavior for "ShowDialogue" is not the "centerparent", whether or not you have multiple threads.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams When I remove the multi-threading the code works perfectly :/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FormStartPosition.CenterParent does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567058/formstartposition-centerparent-does-not-work)

Comment: you're not telling frmSettings about a parent.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Shouldn't it automatically know because of the `ShowDialog`?

Comment: Lots of ways to blow your leg off trying to display a window on a worker thread.  This is a mild one, the window doesn't have a parent.

Comment: @HansPassant How do I assign a parent to the form when opening in another thread?

Comment: A parent should belong to the same thread.  You can force it by pinvoking SetParent().  But that will turn the window in a zombie when the thread that owns that parent window isn't pumping a message loop.  The typical reason to create a window on another thread in the first place.  You therefore should not do this.  Just set its Location property yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant So the code I have right now is the best way to go?

Comment: @FoxyShadoww If you used the `ShowDialog(IWin32Window)` override (e.g. `frmSettings.ShowDialog(someParent);`) it would.  Otherwise, it will take the "main" (or first) form from the current thread.  If there are none, it will think there is no parent.  I'm not sure how WinForms will handle a parent from a different thread though, so, be warned that might fail.

Comment: The notion of "best way" is off the table when you run a window on another thread.  You probably forgot about other stuff, like calling Thread.SetApartmentState() to force an STA.

Comment: And no, ShowDialog(owner) will bomb with an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: @HansPassant Yea, it looks like it :(.

Comment: I would probably do 'this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>ThreadFrmSettings())', which will get around this headache by asynchronously borrowing the main messaging thread.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams This doesn't give any issues later on?

Comment: @FoxyShadoww nope, and I think it is actually the "correct" way to handle this: [all UI updates should be on the main thread, as windows forms are not thread safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Note: "ShowDialogue" will block the main form. If that is not the behavior you want, you should use the "show" call. There are some instances where you want the different forms to have their own messaging threads, like if you are trying to do processor intensive display tasks, but you'll get more bang for your buck using DirectX/OpenGL controls.

Answer (score 0):

What about `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;`  property of the `From`?

I.e.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        Form frmSettings = new Form();
        frmSettings.Width = 300;
        frmSettings.Height = 200;
        frmSettings.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        //frmSettings.Location = new Point(Location.X + (Width - frmSettings.Width) / 2, Location.Y + (Height - frmSettings.Height) / 2);
        frmSettings.ShowDialog();

    }
}
```

Note: `frmSettings.Show();`  gives different result and in that case window is not going to be at the center.

Here is the sample with a thread/task

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

                Form frmSettings = new Form();
                frmSettings.Width = 300;
                frmSettings.Height = 200;
                frmSettings.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

                frmSettings.ShowDialog();

            } );   

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but it desn't put the form into the center of the parent :p. Atleast, not for me.

Comment: @FoxyShadoww Use this line `frmSettings.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;`

Comment: @FoxyShadoww But what do you want in fact? Do you need to shift a little bit your window?

Comment: I need it to be opened at the center of its parent.

Comment: @FoxyShadoww Well.. The code I sent to you is working fine. Perhaps you have some extra settings that suppress the normal behavior.

Comment: I think it works for you because it's not loaded into another thread.

Comment: @FoxyShadoww Make sure that you use frmSettings.ShowDialog(); instead of frmSettings.Show();

Comment: I am, but it still doesn't want to open in the center of the parent :/

Comment: @FoxyShadoww I have updated the code with Task = Thread It is working fine. Try to replace Threads with Tasks.

Comment: Strange, even with your new code it just doesn't seem to be opening itself into the center of the parent :/.

Comment: @FoxyShadoww It is working fine for me. Perhaps you have some trouble with visual studio. Try to reload Windows and execute my code.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed MadScienceDreams's advice and got the result I wanted, this is the code that did the trick:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>ThreadFrmSettings())
```

Comment: `MethodInvoker` from [Microsoft.JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.jscript.methodinvoker.aspx)? That page says "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."