# Child Form not opening at the center of the panel on Master form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

Developing a windows form application using Visual studio 2019 in that on the master form I have taken 2 panels from that 1 panel is to open child form but that child form is not opening on center of the panel

i tried start position property for child form as "Center parent" or "Center Screen" but not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FormStartPosition.CenterParent does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567058/formstartposition-centerparent-does-not-work)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

you should first select the project with ".netFramework".

[image]

WinForm implements a generic form based on the middle of the screen or the middle of the parent form.

I demonstrate a simple login function and pop up a new window.

The parent form is displayed in the middle of the screen.

[image]

The child form is in the middle of the parent form.

[image]

The code logic is: Encapsulates the entity class that operates the database and controls the position of the form. The login function is implemented by querying the database, and the sub-form is displayed. And make the parent form in the middle of the screen and the child form in the middle of the parent form.

```
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Set the form screen to center
        FormBaseOPC.SetScreenMiddle(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            Login();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter empty options, please re-enter");
        }
    }

    public void Login()
    {

        Dao dao = new Dao();//Entity classes encapsulate database operations
        string sql = $"select * from t_user where id='{textBox1.Text}' and psw='{textBox2.Text}'";//sql query database
        IDataReader dc = dao.read(sql);
        if (dc.Read())
        {
            Data.UID = dc["id"].ToString();
            Data.UName = dc["name"].ToString(); //Data entity class encapsulates the data queried from the database
            MessageBox.Show("login successful");
            user1 user = new user1();

           // Make the child form in the middle of the parent form
            FormBaseOPC.SetFormMiddle(user);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login failed");

        }
        dao.DaoClose();
    }
```

Entity class that encapsulates the position of the manipulation form:

```
internal class FormBaseOPC
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 1- Center the form screen
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="form">The form that needs to be centered</param>
    public static void SetScreenMiddle2(Form form)
    {
        if (form != null)
        {
            //Get the screen setting centering effect
            form.SetBounds((Screen.GetBounds(form).Width / 2) - (form.Width / 2),
                (Screen.GetBounds(form).Height / 2) - (form.Height / 2),
                form.Width, form.Height, BoundsSpecified.Location);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 1-The form screen is centered (the system comes with it)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="form">The form that needs to be centered</param>
    public static void SetScreenMiddle(Form form)
    {
        if (form != null)
        {
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 2- Set to center and open relative to the form
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="form">The form that needs to be centered</param>
    public static void SetFormMiddle(Form form)
    {
        if (form != null)
        {
            //Set the form to center relative to the parent form
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            // show the form
            form.ShowDialog();
            //set focus to current form
            form.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Entity class encapsulation code:

```
internal class Dao
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    public SqlConnection connection()
    {
        // write database connection string
        string connStr = "Data source=localhost;Initial Catalog=student;User ID=sa;Password=123456";
        conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        return conn;
    }

    public SqlCommand command(string sql)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection());
        return cmd;
    }

    public int Execute(string sql)
    {
        return command(sql).ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public SqlDataReader read(string sql)
    {
        return command(sql).ExecuteReader();
    }
    public void DaoClose()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}

 internal class Data
 {
     public static string UID = "", UName = "";
 }
```

Code logic for welcome form:

```
    public user1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = $"Welcome to {Data.UName}";
    }
```

WinForm implements a common form based on the middle of the screen or the middle of the parent form: through the login function. The login page is in the middle of the screen, and the child form is in the middle of the parent form.Hope it helps you.