# Open new form inside existing form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have my main form as my application.
Now when I open a new form say to display settings.

```
 FormB bForm = new FormB(this);                
 blpForm.Show();
```

Now this works fine but Form b is a smaller form and it appears outside of the boundaries of my original form. I don't want it to be 'Inside' the original form I just want its initial position to be the centre of the original form.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Set `FormStartPosition = Manual`, then calcualte x,y and set to `blpForm.Location`

Comment: Try read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225741/how-do-you-set-the-startposition-of-a-windows-forms-form-using-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this code ? As Rotem said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8566716/1427849) ,

```
FormB bForm = new FormB ();
bForm .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
bForm .Location = new Point(this.Location.X + (this.Width - bForm.Width) / 2,       
   this.Location.Y + (this.Height - bForm.Height) / 2); //this is just an example , you can customize the location
bForm .Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set its Location yourself, which means that you also have to set its StartPosition to Manual.  It's basic arithmetic to calculate the Location of the dialogue based on the Location and Size of the caller and the Size of the dialogue.