# How to open a child form from another child form?

Tags: c#, winforms, parent-child, mdi

I am working on a Windows application. I have a MainForm (Parent) and several childForm. There is a listview in MainForm that contains a childForm name list and by clicking on each name in the list, the relevant childForm shows and the previous ChildForm closes.

I use this codes to show childForm and close the previous childForm in MainForm.cs (ParentForm):

```
CloseForms();
frm_draft = new frm_ShowDraft();
frm_draft.MdiParent = this;
frm_draft.Show();
```

CloseForm() is a method that checks, which childForm is runnig and closes it.
So far everything is good.

In one of the childforms there is a Button. When the user clicks on it, it should close this childForm and show another. But when I click on the button, childForm2 shows out of MainForm. How can I show it inside of MainForm?

My code in the button click event:

```
this.close();
frm_c2 = new frm_child2();
frm_c2.MdiParent = new MainForm().ParentForm; /// Or this.MdiForm
frm_c2.Show();
```

Comment: If this is `C#` why have you used the `VB.NET` tag?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566582/how-to-centerparent-a-non-modal-form/8566716#8566716).

Comment: @Jinx88909 VB.NET tag?

Comment: @saedbfd it's been removed now as part of the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You should set same MdiForm and call Close at the end:

```
frm_c2 = new frm_child2();
frm_cLetter.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
frm_cLetter.Show();
this.Close();
```

Comment: my problem is that childForm2 shows like a parent Form not childForm. how can i show childForm2 like a childForm inside of MainForm?

Comment: put this.Close() after frm_cLetter.Show()

Comment: i put this.Close() at the end. but shows childForm2 out of MainForm yet

Comment: a person wrote correct answer. i wanted to mark it but remove answer!!!!

Comment: I don't know what happened, but my answer is still there :)
If you want to mark is as correct, there should be big check mark on the left. Check this page for more details - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

> http://www.independent-software.com/weifenluo-dockpanelsuite-tutorial-cookbook/
>
> To show a child form in the main form use the WeiFen Luo library. 
>   This control will make it easier to dock forms into your main form visual studio docking screens
>
> Form with 3 forms inside:

[image]

> Make sure the IsMdiContainter prop is true.

[image]

> Example:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

   Form2 f2 = new Form2(); // create new form

   // dockPanel is an control from WeiFen Luo more info see the link
   // dockPanel control is docked in your mainform.
   // this will open Form2 in the dockPanel and align it left
   f2.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockLeft); 

 }
```

> More docking options:
>
> 1. DockState.Fill docks form in over the hole dockPanel
> 2. DockState.Right docks form at the rightside of the dockPanel
> 3. DockState.Top docks form at the topside of the dockPanel
>
> for more option check the link
>   This control will handel responsifnes of the docking forms and will handle allot of positioning calculations for you.

Comment: what if you try ShowDialog() instead of .Show();

Comment: but i want show childForm inside of MainForm. ShowDialog() open from as a parent not a child.

Comment: I've updated my answer this control will make it easier to dock forms into your main form